# sylius yarn build failed

Tags: symfony, yarnpkg, sylius

I set up sylius project and run yarn build with error.Please help me.
:((

```
yarn v1.22.4 
sylius v1.7.0
node v12.18.1

[03:48:26] 'buildAdmin' errored after 4.02 min
[03:48:26] Error in plugin 'gulp-chug'
Message:
    Gulpfile /var/www/custore/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/gulpfile.babel.js exited with an error :(
Details:
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
[03:48:26] 'build' errored after 4.02 min
[03:48:26] The following tasks did not complete: buildShop
[03:48:26] Did you forget to signal async completion?
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: You should at least specify the version of node/yarn and what version of Sylius you are using.

Comment: yarn  v1.22.4
sylius v1.7.0
thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for me switching to Sylius version 1.6.9 solved it.

I would recommend you attempt the solutions offered on their github issues pages first such as removing `node_modules` and reinstalling using npm instead of yarn or removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then running `npm cache clean --force` followed by `npm install` then `npm run build` or potentially switching versions of NodeJs to use 10.19.

These solutions didn't work for me however switch to 1.6.9 did.